# JQuery vs. JQuery.Min For Sticky Navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I found a "scroll to fixed" sticky navigation that I love, but I'm having trouble getting it to work at my site - http://codepen.io/Guilh/pen/JLKbn

The problem is, they are using JQuery.**min** - http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js and my Wordpress site is using JQuery, the same version 1.11.0, but without the min in the URL.

When I test the code out locally, the JQuery.Min link works, but not my JQuery, even though they are both 1.11.0.  Is there a difference?  The code in the two files looks exactly the same, but one works and the other does not.  I thought min just meant minified so that it is a shorter file and faster load.

Comment: You are correct `min` is just the minified file. There is no difference between the logic. Maybe you have a custom jQuery file?

Comment: I dont think it's custom.  Its the one that comes with wordpress, not my theme located here - http://www.fabfatale.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.0

Comment: Try using an external jquery, not the version that comes with WordPress

Comment: Hmmm, thanks for the idea, but I think I'd like to stick with what Wordpress provides, if possible, so the JQuery code will be updated along with my Wordpress updates and the code seems to be what most plugins use/share. :/

Comment: Press F12 and go to the network or resources tab and find the script that is failing. is it failing to load? or is an error occuring within it.

Comment: I see a potential issue... are you testing with just IE? your script is returning with the mime-type application/javascript which i'm pretty sure will fail in older versions of IE (and newer versions in compatibility mode).

Comment: Im using the latest version of FireFox for a Mac.  Also, the file isn't failing to load because when I view source for my test page, I am able to click to get to my JQuery page.  http://www.fabfatale.com/test.html  If you go to this page and add my JQuery link into the src, it doesn't work. If you add in Google's it works.  They are the same version and look like the same exact file.

Comment: sorry, im a newbie so i can't add multiple URLs in one comment yet.  Here is my JQuery link - http://www.fabfatale.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.0

Comment: @jenniferk Press F12 like Kevin said and click on `Console`. Are there any errors in the Console?

Comment: sorry, my F12 on a mac isn't the same as a PC.  if any of you were to save this file locally http://www.fabfatale.com/test.html and switch out this URL http://www.fabfatale.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.0 for this one http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js does it work with both?

Comment: that's strange.  i just tested it in my chrome and it's not working there for me either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry. I "need 50 reputation to comment". Have you tried seeing if `$` is defined? In some CMS's they run jQuery in no conflict mode so you have to use `jQuery` instead of `$`. To find out go to your firefox console and type in `$` and hit enter. Then type in `jQuery` and hit enter. That will tell you if it's undefined or not.

If you want to use `$(function(){/*code here*/});` but still use `$`, you can pass it using `jQuery(function($){/*code here*/});`. This is all assuming you are running in `noConflict()` mode.

Comment: I don't think this will be the case due to the fact that switching from his jquery to the hosted one fixes the issue.

Comment: @KevinB The local reference to jquery file might be returning a  404 and I think its a valid point to verify/confirm

Comment: He provided a link to it, pasting it into fiddler finds the file just fine

Comment: @KevinB True, but I he's talking about having issues on his Wordpress site and not Codepen, which includes it's own copy of jQuery instead of the exact copy he's using on his Wordpress. I could be mistaken though. (This might be what Chandu is saying too so sorry if it's redundant).

Comment: This is the correct answer. wordpress is appending `jQuery.noConflict` to the js file.

Comment: @miriye i think you may be on to something. i went to FF Inspect Element > Console and see this:  TypeError: $ is not a function
 

<script>var  mn = $(".main-nav");

Comment: @miriye ill give your suggestion a shot.

Comment: @miriye it worked it worked it worked!  oh my word.  thank you so much for your help.  (by the way, I'm a she :P). thanks again and again!

Comment: @jenniferk I just tested it on a local version of Wordpress and it appears to be the case.